# how to get value from list in java using LIFERAY 6.2

Tags: java, maven, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.2 comunity and JAVA Maven.
I want to get value from List but i always received name of that class.
Here is my code :

```
@ResourceMapping(value="getDetailSchd")
public void getDetailSchd(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) throws Exception,IOException {
        ClassListDao listDao = new ClassListDao();
        List<ClassList> list = listDao.listSchdByidroom(tt_room_id);
        System.out.println("list="+list);

        response.getWriter();
}
```

and the value from list is "ClassList@5624"

so, how can i display that value ?

This is another code :

Model

```
package com.spring.maven.model;

public class ClassList {
    private Integer tt_schd_id;
    private String coursetranscript;
    private String name_related;
    public Integer getTt_schd_id() {
        return tt_schd_id;
    }
    public void setTt_schd_id(Integer tt_schd_id) {
        this.tt_schd_id = tt_schd_id;
    }
    public String getCoursetranscript() {
        return coursetranscript;
    }
    public void setCoursetranscript(String coursetranscript) {
        this.coursetranscript = coursetranscript;
    }
    public String getName_related() {
        return name_related;
    }
    public void setName_related(String name_related) {
        this.name_related = name_related;
    }
}
```

DAO

```
public List<ClassList> listSchdByidroom(Integer id) throws Exception{
        if(id == null){
            return null;
        }
        DatabaseConnection dbcon = new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection con = dbcon.openConnect();
        List<ClassList> values = new ArrayList<ClassList>();

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlGetSchdByidroom );
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();       
        while(rs.next()){
            ClassList classList = konversiResult2(rs);
            values.add(classList);
        }
        con.close();    
        return values;
    }
```

Comment: You should note also that you are using Spring. Liferay is just the portal where you portlet runs...

Comment: what do you mean by value ? is it the toString representation of your List ,JSON repreentation , plain HTML ??

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send that responce back to the view as it is :

```
response.getWriter().println(list);
```

if you want a json representation of that List :

- add dependencies for `Jackson`:

  ```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.8</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.9</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Change the method :

  ```
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
   ....
  @ResourceMapping(value="getDetailSchd")
  public void getDetailSchd(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse  response) throws Exception,IOException {
              ClassListDao listDao = new ClassListDao();
              List<ClassList> list = listDao.listSchdByidroom(tt_room_id);
              System.out.println("list="+list);

      OutputStream outStream = res.getPortletOutputStream();
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      mapper.writeValue(outStream, list);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

i use this code and it's working :

```
JSONArray stateArray = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray();       

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

    JSONObject stateObject;
    stateObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();

    System.out.println("data ke["+i+"] = "+list.get(i).getTt_schd_id());
    stateObject.put("tt_schd_id", list.get(i).getTt_schd_id());
    stateArray.put(stateObject);

}
response.getWriter().println(stateArray);
```

I read that tutorial from [here](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/01/content-auto-update-using-jquery-ajax.html) .

Thanks for all of you.